# IE8 jQuery propagation - Click anywhere on screen activates scroll

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, event-propagation

This jQuery code works great on all browsers except IE8. What happens is that when I click anywhere on a page in IE8, whether on a link, a div or just in the white space, it will activate the scroll event. I think it is a propagation problem, and I have nailed it down to a specific chunk of jQuery (see comments in jQuery below), but I'm not sure how to change it so that it works correctly in IE8. It should obviously only scroll when the element chosen is clicked.

**jQuery:**

```
$(".scroll, .tobottom, .video-cta").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = "#" + $(this).data("target") + " h1";
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, {duration: 2000, easing: "easeInOutQuint"});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Blah blah blah</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic|Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <script>window.html5 || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/html5shiv.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if gte IE 9]>
          <style type="text/css">
            .gradient {
               filter: none;
            }
          </style>
        <![endif]-->

        <link href="video-js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="video-js/video.js"></script>
        <script>
            videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js/video-js.swf";
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Video */
            .videocontent {width: 100%; max-width: 640px;}
            .video-js {padding-top: 56.25%;}
            .vjs-fullscreen {padding-top: 0px;}
        </style>


        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
            ga('create', 'UA-56802153-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>


    </head>
    <body>

        <header class="gradient">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a class="top" href="index.html">Blah blah blah</a>
                </div>
                <div class="subheading">
                    <p><i>Blah blah blah</i></p>
                    <a class="tobottom" href="#" data-target="stayconnected" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Navigation', 'Home', 'Register for Updates']);">Register for updates</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="pages">
            <section class="deeper wrap">
                <div class="heading-hr">
                    <h1>Blah blah blah</h1>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <p>Blah blah blah</p>
                <p>Blah blah blah</p>
                <div class="heading-hr">
                    <h2>Are <b>you</b> ready?</h2>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="scroll with-heading" id="container-video" data-target="videoseries">
                    <p class="start-exploring">Start Exploring</p>
                    <div id="allArrows-video">
                        <img src="img/scroll/arrow1.png" id="arrow1-video" class="arrow-video" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/arrow2.png" id="arrow2-video" class="arrow-video" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/arrow3.png" id="arrow3-video" class="arrow-video" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/arrow4.png" id="arrow4-video" class="arrow-video" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="allBubbles-video">
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble1.png" id="bubble1-video" class="bubble-video" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble2.png" id="bubble2-video" class="bubble-video" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble3.png" id="bubble3-video" class="bubble-video" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble4.png" id="bubble4-video" class="bubble-video" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble5.png" id="bubble5-video" class="bubble-video" />
                    </div>
                <div>
            </section>
            <section id="videoseries" class="videoseries wrap">
                <h1>Blah blah blah</h1>
                <div class="video">
                    <div class="videocontent">
                        <video id="promo-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload width="auto" height="auto" poster="video/video-series/promo.jpg" data-setup='{"techOrder": ["flash", "html5"]}'>
                            <source src="video/video-series/promo.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
                            <source src="video/video-series/promo.webm" type='video/webm' />
                            <source src="video/video-series/promo.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
                            <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
                        </video>
                        <script>
                            //reference the player
                            var myPlayer = videojs("promo-video");
                            //provide a name for the Events
                            var videoTitle = "Blah blah blah";
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="videodescription">
                    <h2>Blah blah blah</h2>
                    <p>Blah blah blah</p>
                    <a class="button video-cta" href="#" data-target="stayconnected" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Button', 'Home', 'Sign up to stay informed']);">Sign up to stay informed</a>
                </div>
                <div id="container-address" class="scroll" data-target="addresschallenges">
                    <div id="allArrows-address">
                        <img src="img/scroll/arrow1.png" id="arrow1-address" class="arrow-address" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/arrow2.png" id="arrow2-address" class="arrow-address" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/arrow3.png" id="arrow3-address" class="arrow-address" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/arrow4.png" id="arrow4-address" class="arrow-address" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="allBubbles-address">
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble1.png" id="bubble1-address" class="bubble-address" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble2.png" id="bubble2-address" class="bubble-address" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble3.png" id="bubble3-address" class="bubble-address" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble4.png" id="bubble4-address" class="bubble-address" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble5.png" id="bubble5-address" class="bubble-address" />
                    </div>
                <div>
            </section>
            <section id="addresschallenges" class="addresschallenges wrap">
                <h1>Blah blah blah</h1>
                <div class="challenges">
                    <div class="ie-left"><p>Blah blah blah</p></div>
                    <div class="ie-middle"><p>Blah blah blah</p></div>
                    <div class="ie-right"><p>Blah blah blah</p></div>
                </div>
                <div id="container-connected" class="scroll" data-target="stayconnected">
                    <div id="allArrows-connected">
                        <img src="img/scroll/arrow1.png" id="arrow1-connected" class="arrow-connected" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/arrow2.png" id="arrow2-connected" class="arrow-connected" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/arrow3.png" id="arrow3-connected" class="arrow-connected" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/arrow4.png" id="arrow4-connected" class="arrow-connected" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="allBubbles-connected">
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble1.png" id="bubble1-connected" class="bubble-connected" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble2.png" id="bubble2-connected" class="bubble-connected" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble3.png" id="bubble3-connected" class="bubble-connected" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble4.png" id="bubble4-connected" class="bubble-connected" />
                        <img src="img/scroll/bubble5.png" id="bubble5-connected" class="bubble-connected" />
                    </div>
                <div>
            </section>
            <section id="stayconnected" class="stayconnected">
                <h1>Stay <b>connected</b> to the latest news</h1>
                <div class="form">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <form class="cmxform" id="scForm" method="post" action="" pageId="4648716" siteId="147979" parentPageId="4648715">
                            <p class="join-us">Blah blah blah</p>
                            <div class="personal-info-test">
                                <div class="ie-left">
                                    <div class="table-field">
                                        <div class="first-row">
                                            <div id="firstName-error"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="last-row">
                                            <div>
                                                <label class="hide" for="firstName">First name</label><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First name"> <span>*</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ie-middle">
                                    <div class="table-field">
                                        <div class="first-row">
                                            <div id="lastName-error"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="last-row">
                                            <div>
                                                <label class="hide" for="lastName">Last name</label><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last name"> <span>*</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ie-right">
                                    <div class="table-field">
                                        <div class="first-row">
                                            <div id="email-error"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="last-row">
                                            <div>
                                                <label class="hide" for="email">Email address</label><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address"> <span>*</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p class="required-fields">* Required fields</p>
                            <p class="agreement">Blah blah blah</p>
                            <input type="hidden" name="formSourceName" value="StandardForm">
                            <input type="hidden" name="sp_exp" value="yes">
                            <div class="submit-button"><input type="submit" value="Register for Updates" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Button', 'Register for Updates', 'Register for Updates']);"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="footer-home wrap">
                <footer>
                    <p class="text-center"><img src="img/logo-blah-large.png" alt="Blah logo"></p>
                    <p>Blah blah blah</p>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="tos.html" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Navigation', 'Home', 'Terms of Use']);">Terms of Use</a></li>
                            <li><a href="privacy.html" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Navigation', 'Home', 'Privacy Policy']);">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <p class="trademark">Blah blah blah</p>
                    <p>Blah blah blah</p>
                </footer>
            </section>
        </div>

        <div class="success-overlay"></div>
        <div class="success-message">
            <span>X</span>
            <h1>Thank you for participating</h1>
            <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        </div>

        <script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-validation-1.13.1/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-validation-1.13.1/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.validator.addMethod("nonumbers", function(value, element, regexpr) {
                return regexpr.test(value);
            });
            $.validator.addMethod("testemail", function(value, element, regexpr) {
                return regexpr.test(value);
            });
            $("#scForm").validate({
                debug: false,
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    var errorid = "#" + $(error).attr("id");
                    var container = $(element).parent().parent().parent().find(errorid);
                    error.appendTo(container);
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    document.location.href = "index.html#stayconnected"
                    $(".success-overlay").show();
                    $(".success-message").show();
                    $(".success-message span").on("click",function(){
                        $(".success-overlay").hide();
                        $(".success-message").hide();
                        $("#firstName, #lastName, #email").val("");
                    });
                    form.submit();
                },
                rules: {
                    firstName: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 1,
                        nonumbers: /^[A-Za-z-]+$/
                    },
                    lastName: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 1,
                        nonumbers: /^[A-Za-z-]+$/
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                        testemail: /^\w{2,}@\w{2,}\.\w{2,}$/
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    firstName: {
                        required: "Please enter your first name",
                        minlength: "Please enter a valid first name",
                        nonumbers: "Only letters and dashes"
                    },
                    lastName: {
                        required: "Please enter your last name",
                        minlength: "Please enter a valid last name",
                        nonumbers: "Only letters and dashes"
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: "Please enter your email address",
                        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                        testemail: "Please enter a valid email address"
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer.  However, please edit your OP to specifically state which jQuery version you're using.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

On [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27068841/594235) that I deleted, the OP stated he was using jQuery 1.11.1, which rules out my idea that he was using jQuery 2 which does not support IE 8.

---

As per [the W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org), the code you posted contains 44 errors including unclosed container elements.  Internet Explorer cannot handle invalid HTML as well as other browsers, and without standards compliant code, browsers can behave unpredictably.

These are the most notable errors...

- > Line 6, Column 70: A meta element with an http-equiv attribute whose value is X-UA-Compatible must have a content attribute with the value IE=edge.
- > Line 92, Column 21: Unclosed element div.
- > Line 77, Column 96: Unclosed element div.
- > Line 93, Column 22: End tag section seen, but there were open elements.
- > Line 132, Column 22: End tag section seen, but there were open elements.
- > Line 131, Column 21: Unclosed element div.
- > Line 155, Column 22: End tag section seen, but there were open elements.
- > Line 154, Column 21: Unclosed element div.
- > Line 140, Column 89: Unclosed element div.

http://validator.w3.org